# Getting a number with a < in front in a spreadsheet to show up as a while number in a graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet with data from environmental testing. Some of the results have a < in front of them, such as <0.35 and <5.0. I want the numbers to show up in the line graph as .35 and 5.0, but Excel will only recognize it as zero. Is there any way I can fix that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Create a column with this formula and drag it down in front of <0.35...

`=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"<",""))`
Substitute will find < and replace it with empty ("")
Value to convert text to number
A1 is your Data in the form <0.35...
And finally copy the result column and paste special values to have the result fixed number (you can delete other column and keep the paste special values at the end)
Now you can draw the line graph